# disable options on select in other dropdowns except 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

So I have a script her that kinda does what i want for the most part but there are 3 things that it doesn't do and I would like it to do....

1. Make it so the <del>selects</del> option with 0 value can always be selected and never disabled
2. Disable <del>selects</del> option in all other drop downs that have already been selected on load except <del>selects</del> option with a value of 0 of course.
3. with this code you can some how you can disable all the options in the lists... I dont want it to do this... if you select an option and want to make enable it again for other dropdowns, if you play with the dropdowns you will see what i am talking about.

Any help with this is extremely appreciated! Im not very good with JS/JQuery at all.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").on('hover', function() {
    $previousValue = $(this).val();
  }).change(function() {
    $("select").not(this).find("option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']").attr('disabled', true);
    $("select").not(this).find("option[value='" + $previousValue + "']").attr('disabled', false);

  });

});

$("#confirm-form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("select").find("option").removeAttr('disabled');
  document.getElementById('confirm-form').submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<select id="select1">
  <option value="0">--Please choose--</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select id="select2">
  <option value="0">--Please choose--</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select id="select3">
  <option value="0">--Please choose--</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select id="select4">
  <option value="0">--Please choose--</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
```

edit: made this a little more clear, sorry for confusion

Comment: Your english is quite confusing tbh. When are the other selects supposed to be disabled? Does select1 affect select2?

Comment: when an option is chosen, the value that was selected should be disabled where that value exists in all the other selects.  So if I select option 1(value=1) in the first select then option 1(value=1) in select 2,3,4... etc also are disabled

Comment: That makes more sense when you put it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local variable `previousValue` is not supposed to work outside a function except in two cases, returned, or scoped, so this is why you should capture it for using it inside the neighbor function `change()`.

```js
// Add your javascript here
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").focus(function() {
      previousValue = $(this).val();
      console.log(previousValue);
  $(this).change(
     function() {
      if($(this).val()!=="0"){
      $("select").not(this).find("option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']").attr('disabled', true);}
      $("select").not(this).find("option[value='" + previousValue + "']").attr('disabled', false);    
     })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1"> 
  <option value="0">--Please choose--</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select id="select2">
  <option value="0">--Please choose--</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select id="select3">
  <option value="0">--Please choose--</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select id="select4">
  <option value="0">--Please choose--</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
```